# Chat with spreadsheet using meta-llama/Llama-2-13b-chat-hf

Tags: langchain, nlp-question-answering, large-language-model, h2o.ai, llama

I made a spreadsheet which contain around 2000 question-answer pair and use meta-llama/Llama-2-13b-chat-hf model. But when start querying through the spreadsheet using the above model it gives wrong answers most of the time & also repeat it many times.
So I want to know that what kind of docs format & it's structure i should try for question-answering & how can i resolve the above problem.

Kindly help me!

I using meta-llama/Llama-2-13b-chat-hf model and set temperature 0.1, top-p 0.75, top-k 40, max_output_length 1024, repetition penalty 1.07 and chunk size for document chunking 512. these are the hyper parameters i tried when prompting.

Comment: Could you include some code?

Comment: Maybe try exporting the spreadsheet into plain text with "question N": "answer N" per line.

Comment: https://github.com/h2oai/h2ogpt/issues/630